# How to cancel button events

Tags: ios

Ok, to be simple: in my app I've got slider and a button. When the user touches the button a timer starts and increments progres on slider. I also have touch up event, so when you take back your finger while timer slider has not reached the end yet it comes back to the zero state. When it reaches the end I want to hide both controls. And here comes the problem: button is already hidden (i tried userInteractionEnabled=NO too) but it still responds to touch up events and it triggers when i take my finger back from the place the button was before hiding. How can I disable this action?
(I hope everything is clear)

Comment: add some code. You need to set `selected` or `enabled` in method when your app reaches the end.

Answer (score 0):

set the property

say u hav a UIButton named aButton

```
     aButton.enabled = NO ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button.selected = NO;
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to stop the event from firing, I would just check in the event handler whether the "end" has been reached or not, and not reset if it has. That way the code is less prone to an error if the UI doesn't work ex